# How do I get the children of an Element in Watin?

Tags: c#, watin

Given the following html:

```
<ul id="search-results">
   <li>
        <h3>Result 1</h3>
        <span class="some-info">Tag line</span>
   </li>
   <li>
        <h3>Result 2</h3>
        <span class="some-info">Another bit</span>
   </li>
   <li>
        <h3>Result 2</h3>
        <span class="some-info">Another bit</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I can get the `ul` element with:

```
Element ul = ie.Element(Find.ById("search-results"));
```

How do I iterate over the children of the `search-results`?

I've managed to get as far as:

```
var allListItems = ie.Elements.Filter(e => e.Parent != null && e.Parent.Id == "search-results");
```

But this doesn't help me assert things about the H3 or span contained within the `li`'s.

Comment: I think you meant "descendants", not "children". I suggest changing this just for future user's searches.

Comment: descendants implies I'm interested in *all* nodes under 'search-results', initially I want to find only the descendants whose parent node is 'search-results'. This consistant with api's like jQuery.

Comment: So you are interested only in `li` elements? Because `h3` and `span` don't have `ul` as parent. They have `ul` as ancestor and `li` as parent. Also note that `Elements` in `IElementContainer` will give you descendants, not children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option1:**Based on your code, you can try something like:

```
ie.Spans.Filter(Find.ByClass("some-info"))[0...2].PreviousSibling;
```

you will need to loop over each span.

**Option2:**Based on some suggestions from the Watin mail list (similar to your own answer as well):

```
IElementContainer elem = (IElementContainer)ie.Element(Find.ById("search-results"));
```

Then you parse through `elem.Element`

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty similar to my own answer... I just can't believe that an Element can't find it's own children

Answer (score 7):

Current best hack I can think of is:

```
public static class WatinExtensions
{
    public static ElementCollection Children(this Element self)
    {
        return self.DomContainer.Elements.Filter(e => self.Equals(e.Parent));
    }
}


ElementCollection results = ie.Element(Find.ById("search-results")).Children();

// and 

foreach(Element li in results)
{
    Element info = li.Children().First(e => e.ClassName.Contains("some-info"));
}
```

<strike>It works but surely there is a proper why to do this?</strike>

[And there is a correct way to do this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=AANLkTi%3Dmi8DAMCK0C7CPBX9su8_yVBDfn0EbP8Nd31ny%40mail.gmail.com) from the watin mailing list:

In my example:

```
var searchResults = (IElementContainer) ie.Element(Find.ById("search-results"));

foreach (Element element in searchResults.Elements) {
    // can do more here
}
```

Comment: Great solution to your own question! I'll include Children on Element for the next release of WatiN. Already implemented for the next release is support for ol and ul by browser.List() and support for li elements by browser.ListItem(). HTH, Jeroen.

Comment: great stuff, WatiN is a great library, thanks for the all the effort